# Удаление Visual Studio Code с системы Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Я недано установил Visual Studio Code (com.visualstudio.code) с помощью Flatpak с репозитория Flathub, позже я захотел удалить его (Visual Studio Code), удалил, но файлы ещё остались в системе Linux (Linux Mint), в папке /var/lib/flatpak/.removed/. У меня появился вопрос. Безопасно удалять там файлы и папки? В интернете не написано на эту тему ничего

Comment: Ну раз папка скрытая и называется соответствуююще - чисть без проблем. Скорее всего эта папка нужна для того, чтобы не качать заново дистр, если пользователь передумает и захочет поставить заново.

Comment: О, нашёл https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1835

Comment: Спасибо за информацию